# How to calculate current day and previous day value in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Good afternoon, I have the following scenario, on day o1, I have the balance, and day by day it is subtracting the transactions, and I need to calculate the balance at the beginning and end of the day, does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this in pyspark?
imput:

[image]

expected exit:

[image]

Comment: Next time, please don't use screenshots. There's a mistake and it's hard to change it. Also, we cannot copy-paste your example if it's just screenshots, so we need to write everything manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, the logic is correct. You're right thinking about the `lag` window function. But I think it's best to use it after you already have calculated the end_date.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(10499.84,   0.00, '2022-02-01'),
     (    0.00,   0.00, '2022-02-02'),
     (    0.00,   0.00, '2022-02-03'),
     (    0.00,   0.00, '2022-02-04'),
     (    0.00, 245.70, '2022-02-05'),
     (    0.00,  70.88, '2022-02-06'),
     (    0.00,   0.00, '2022-02-07'),
     (    0.00,   0.00, '2022-02-08'),
     (    0.00, 119.84, '2022-02-09')],
    ['saldo', 'trans', 'day']
)
w = W.orderBy('day')
df = df.withColumn('end_day', F.sum(F.col('saldo') - F.col('trans')).over(w))
df = df.withColumn('begin_day', F.coalesce(F.lag('end_day').over(w), F.sum('saldo').over(w)))
df = df.select('saldo', 'trans', 'begin_day', 'end_day', 'day')

df.show()
# +--------+------+---------+--------+----------+
# |   saldo| trans|begin_day| end_day|       day|
# +--------+------+---------+--------+----------+
# |10499.84|   0.0| 10499.84|10499.84|2022-02-01|
# |     0.0|   0.0| 10499.84|10499.84|2022-02-02|
# |     0.0|   0.0| 10499.84|10499.84|2022-02-03|
# |     0.0|   0.0| 10499.84|10499.84|2022-02-04|
# |     0.0| 245.7| 10499.84|10254.14|2022-02-05|
# |     0.0| 70.88| 10254.14|10183.26|2022-02-06|
# |     0.0|   0.0| 10183.26|10183.26|2022-02-07|
# |     0.0|   0.0| 10183.26|10183.26|2022-02-08|
# |     0.0|119.84| 10183.26|10063.42|2022-02-09|
# +--------+------+---------+--------+----------+
```

If you restart every month, you should use this window:

```
w = W.partitionBy(F.year('day'), F.month('day')).orderBy('day')
```

You may also need to `round` your end_day.